# Serial Selection of picklist by using Trigger!

Tags: apex, trigger, validation

I have a Picklist field Called 
`Status__c` in this i have values like `picklist 1,picklist 2,picklist 3,picklist 4,picklist 5,picklist 6` here i will start selecting values from `picklist 1` and next picklist value should be `picklist 2` not `picklist 3` or `picklist 4`. if they select like that means it should through error.How to achive this.

Thanks

Comment: Create a Dependency between the pick-list

Comment: on one field how to create dependency ?

Comment: My bad, You have only one field right.  actually what you wanted to achieve with selecting continuously different value on same field ?

Comment: Something you can do like , you have to keep one property to keep predicting next value. When you change picklist value, You have compare with predicted value. if true then predict next value else throw error.

Comment: yes @NITHESHK can you give me any sample code regading this?

Comment: What you have tried? Where you got struck ?

Answer (score 1):

Below is sample logic i have added.

when a page is loaded i have written constructor to taken value of the picklist and added to list called **pickListValuesIntoList**.  From the that **pickListValuesIntoList** i am taking first value  as **nextPicklistValue** to compare the next **selectedPicklistValue** , will be **picklist 1** in your case.

**ChangeInPicklistSelection()** function is will check whether you have select the correct pick-list value , If it is correct next index of  **pickListValuesIntoList** value is **nextPicklistValue**, otherwise return **error** as you required.

```
public class ClassName {
    public List<String> pickListValuesIntoList;
    public String nextPicklistValue;
    public Integer nextSize;
    public String selectedPicklistValue;

    public ClassName() {
        pickListValuesIntoList= new  List<String>();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = ObjectApiName.FieldApiName.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
        for( Schema.PicklistEntry pickListVal : ple){
            pickListValuesIntoList.add(pickListVal.getLabel());
        }   
        if(pickListValuesList.size()>0){
            nextSize=0; //assuming no value is selected at begining , otherwise use index 1
            nextPicklistValue=pickListValuesList[nextSize];
        }            
    }

    public void ChangeInPicklistSelection(){
        if(selectedPicklistValue.equals(nextPicklistValue)){
            // When next picklist selected correctly            
            if(pickListValuesList.size()>nextSize){
            nextSize++;
            nextPicklistValue=pickListValuesList[nextSize];            
             }   
        }
        else {
            // throw error 
        }
    }  
}
```

Also write a **actionSupport** for picklist change. and **actionSupport** will call **ChangeInPicklistSelection()** function.